# ¿Cómo obtener el id del caso en bonitasoft 7.3?

Tags: bonita

Buenos días el motivo de mi pregunta es sobre como capturar el id del caso en bonita soft estoy utilizado un formulario 6.x  al momento de buscar información sobre como realizar el procedimiento no encuentro información fácil de entender soy nuevo utilizado el programa si alguin sabe como se puede realizar el proceso o en donde puede enconar  información sobre el tema para poder empezar a programar por que no se ni por donde empezar . Estoy utilizado el editor groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para obtener el  id del caso se tiene que utilizar el processInstanceId que almacena información sobre el procedimiento

```js
def process = apiAccessor .getProcessAPI().getProcessInstance(processInstanceId);
return process.id.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira en esta URL Es esta la foro de ayuda no tiene los datos de stack pero algo de ayuda tiene 
 https://community.bonitasoft.com

Codigo

```
import org.bonitasoft.engine.api.IdentityAPI;
import org.bonitasoft.engine.identity.User;

IdentityAPI identity = apiAccessor.getIdentityAPI();
User user = identity.getUserByUserName(demandReviewer);

return user.getId();
```

Comment: gracias francisco por tu respuesta pero el código que  me publicaste  es para tener el id de usuario  por la etiqueta  o nombre del usuario, yo necesitaba era el id de caso que genera el sistema al momento de comenzar el proceso